# Plotly line chart_'module' object is not callable why this error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, plotly-python

I am plotting a line chart using plotly from a pivot table. But getting an error module' object is not callable when I try to plot, till that no issues. May I know why this is coming? Please see my code below

```
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
df1 = pd.read_csv("Funct_TDH_RISE_Corners_2p0_A.txt",delim_whitespace=True) 
df1.to_csv('TDH.csv',index=False)
df1['SPEC_MIN']=5
df1['SPEC_MAX']=30
df1
TDH_PVT= pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ['Device_ID'],values = ['TDH_Rise[ns]'])
  #When I try to run the below code error is coming  
data=[go.Scatter(
            x=TDH_PVT.index,
            y=TDH_PVT.values,
            mode='lines',
            name='TDH_RISE'
    )]
    layout=go.layout(title='TDH RISE')
    figure=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
    pyo.plot(figure)
```

My pivot table is given below

```
    TDH_Rise[ns]
Device_ID   
FF_2649 19.228333
FF_2650 19.499167
FF_2651 19.365000
FS_2859 20.425000
FS_2860 20.252500
FS_2861 20.557500
SF_2754 21.700000
SF_2755 21.743333
SF_2756 21.528000
SS_2544 21.678333
SS_2545 21.642500
SS_2546 21.655000
TT_2439 20.730000
TT_2440 20.688333
TT_2441 18.642500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual plotly method is `Layout`. As python is case sensitive it is not recognising the method and so throwing the not callable exception. Just need to change line

```
layout=go.layout(title='TDH RISE')
```

to

```
layout=go.Layout(title='TDH RISE')
```

Answer (score 0):

- bootstrap upper lower floor ceilings and alter per nodes var.b
- check the syntax on the whitespace, add s.
- I would use '"idx"', "make_union", assists by grouping two dfs, (df1,df2).
- performing more granular level lims' xor subs.
- use abr, aprx, **idx**, best_fit, ***

> triangulation patterns(Fourier)-h / **dequeue**.linked(priority) | chain.attrs.map.map(Map) for meta.

***, knn, euclidean

- increase samples from min_samples_name=int,
- underfit the model, allow auto.py.gui for mapping procedures for new win32 pop up/ interactive.
- "==" for bottom two shapes/fig \
- use dot or Rsq in congruency with the triangulation (Euclidean /
  Manhattan) call to calls(recursive), if node path leaves initiative.
- memory=None
- warm_start=T/F for usage calls.
- have you tried scoring mechanisms? scoring='accuracy'
- n_jobs=-1
- Gini criterion
- for the pivot, use null xor start for later time under a set | cond.
- **I had to perform a very similar process, and my approach was much different, as it was population, density, foot traffic and density based with erroneous factors, bases, subs, triangulation of est, rsq, differential, partial differentiation,(pred - actuals) and data points were all able to be referenced back.** to initial call.
- a great though advanced, "pyautogui" will perform get [actions;] [].collect

|N|_n=bias*err*weights(w, x, rec)_*in.dot(xwa, xwb, xwc)*dist(euc(x)):
err.%* for 'i' in weighted(i, j)range,
else:
J =0,
return J-jw(x**2i)/n(map)
J = future distance, add *args based on conditions as in a filter.